# How to EV code-sign ClickOnce applications?

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, clickonce, code-signing

How is everyone else doing this?

We were previously signing our code using EVCS + hardware token (Yubikey) via SSL.com but have recently had alot of issues. It now appears as though this is no longer supported: https://www.ssl.com/blogs/new-minimum-rsa-key-size-for-code-signing-certificates/

As an interim solution we are using their eSigner solution but have found it very expensive, not transparent and with dubious billing practices.

What is the current best practice for signing ClickOnce deployment using Visual Studio? How is everyone else signing their applications? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the problem I'm having, many people now use sha384 code signing certificates.

However, if you use it before vs2022, it seems that there will be some problems, see this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73399453/16764901) for details.

For ev code signing maybe you can try this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1225324/How-to-Sign-ClickOnce-Deployment-if-ClickOnce-Code).

---

Rhom's Update:
I have an open ticket and more detailed explanation of the issue here

https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/256

Comment: I am using VS2022 and have been following that article and having success.
I'll post back here once I have the full procedure locked down but not using that tab in Visual Studio seems to be the correct path forward. Thanks

Comment: Just an update. I managed to sin my executables but could not get ClickOnce mage.exe to sign the manifest files. I have opened a ticket here: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/30534

Comment: I have an open ticket and more detailed explanation of the issue here: https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/issues/256

Comment: I have added it to the answer to help the people who have the same issue.